# SVN 1.2.3 to 1.7 Migration Dump Load issues

Tags: svn, repository, dump, migration

I am having trouble with migrating a SVN (version 1.2.3) repo to a new server. In the process I want to update the repo and server to the latest SVN version.

I have tried dumping the repo, but found I run into a few 'malformed' revisions. Google-fu'd a bit and found a suggestion to do the dump in batches and skip the broken revisions.

Unfortunately, trying to load the dumped files is causing all sorts of issues...
1. If I try and load it directly, I receive 'non-LF' endings found errors. I try converting the line endings using notepad++ to unix format, but this doesn't seem to work. 
2. I can use 'bypass-prop-validation' on the load. this works, but when I load a later dump file(revisions after the malformed ones I skipped).. it appears the skipped revisions are referenced and I am getting 'checksum mismatch' errors.

I am really after just a clear and clean way to try and upgrade and migrate the repository.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the subversion repository for any outstanding transactions by means of the `svnadmin lstxns` command. Clean up any uncompleted transactions per pages around 502 in the free [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.pdf) before you try another `svnadmin dump`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svnsync. Svnsync allows you to recreate the repositories with the advantage of using the benefits for the 1.7 version.